# API call with for loop doesn't loop through a list in Python

Tags: python, api, for-loop

I'm trying to make an API call to coinmarketcap to get the prices for a crypto portfolio and append the prices to a list.

The portfolio is on an excel file. I'm reading the excel with pandas, then looping through the "project" column of the dataframe and appending the names to a list called "project_list".

Then I'm making the API call, and looping through the previously created "project_list", and trying to get the price for each project, and finally appending those prices to an empty list called "price_list".

But when I run the code, it gives and IndexError, IndexError: list index out of range.

But the curious thing is, if I populate the project list manually, the code works just fine.

I thought this might be because I'm appending to the list dynamically and it's not ready by the time the API call is made. But I tried doing other things with the list right after appending, and they all work fine..

Code is below and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Step 1: Read the Excel File

```
crypto_df = pd.read_excel('D:\Trading\CRYPTO\Crypto Portfolio Tracker.xlsx')
```

Step 2: Create project_list and append the names from the dataframe

```
project_list = []
for name in crypto_df['Project'].values:
project_list.append(name)
```

Step 3: Making the API call

```
class CMC:

def __init__(self, token):
    self.apiurl = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com'
    self.headers = {'Accepts': 'application/json', 'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': token, }
    self.session = Session()  # instead of requesting url through requests, we are requesting through sessions.
    self.session.headers.update(self.headers)

def get_all_coins(self):
    url = self.apiurl + '/v1/cryptocurrency/map'
    r = self.session.get(url)
    data = r.json()['data']
    return data

def get_price(self, symbol):
    url = self.apiurl + '/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'
    parameters = {'symbol': symbol}
    r = self.session.get(url, params=parameters)
    data = r.json()['data']
    return data
```

Step 4: Appending the prices to price_list

```
price_list = []
cmc = CMC(secrets_.API_KEY)
for crypto in project_list:
    price = cmc.get_price(crypto)
    price_list.append(price[crypto][0]['quote']['USD']['price'])
print(price_list)
```

And this gives the Index Error.

If I manually populate the project_list, for example project_list = ['ETH', 'BTC', 'ADA', 'LINK', etc..] it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is going to be hard to troubleshoot without knowing what your `crypto_df` looks like, and what exactly is the error (and traceback) you are getting.

Comment: Just look at the list with the index error and look at the index you used, and it should be pretty obvious. We can't do that without the error trace or any data, but maybe price[crypto] == []?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding guys. I figured it out. There's nothing wrong with my code. Coinmarketcap has a limit on requests/min for basic plan(free) API. So if my list is too big, it's throwing an error. When I reduced my list down to only a few currencies, it worked. I still can't be sure exactly how many I can add to the list, it varies with the amount of requests they are getting I guess.